# Number of Breadcrumbs on Google SERP is one less than it should be

Tags: search-results, breadcrumbs

My site has been in existence for more than 2 years now and pages are well indexed in Google.
However, I am struggling to get the correct number and type of breadcrumbs despite the long running efforts over the last 2 years:

For instance, on my page, I have setup FOUR levels of breadcrumbs which are as follows:

```
"@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com",
        "name": "example.com"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/stock/index.php",
        "name": "Major Pharmaceuticals Sector"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/stock/list/index.php",
        "name": "Stock List"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 4,
    "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/stock/list/major-pharmaceuticals.php",
        "name": "List"
}}]
```

However, there are two problems. On the Google Search Results Page,

1. Only THREE show up as follows instead of the FOUR that I have configured:

> ```
> https://example.com › Major Pharmaceuticals Sector › Stock List
> ```

2. Another problem is that in the first one, it is displaying the name of the website which is set in `@id` tag. Shouldn't it show the value set in the "name" tag (name    `example.com`) as I've configured in the code?

Above two problems are common to ALL the webpages (and their respective breadcrumbs display). For instance, the page `/dividend/thld.php` has THREE breadcrumbs but SERP shows only TWO (`example.com › Threshold Pharma (THLD) Dividend History`)

Am I doing something wrong here or is it the way Google works?

Comment: Hello @Anuvesh, while you have edited the question and replaced the mention of site "fknol.com" with "example.com", it would have been better to let it remain with fknol.com. That would help readers check the code (if they need to) and identify the precise problem with a fix. Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! It is standard practice on this platform to inhibit new contributors from adding links to their websites. If anyone wants to access the original links, they can view the last edit and do the same.

Comment: You say it is for all pages, but I suspect it may have something to do with the length of the text in your breadcrumbs.   Do you have a page that uses only one word (or maybe two) for each of the levels of breadcrumbs?  Does that page show all the levels?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, its for ALL pages. The last level of breadcrumbs is never visible on SERP, and first level is always the https://fknol.com instead of the name that I am setting (Fknol.com). Not advertising my site here, but you may get a better picture of the issues if you do a google search with "site:fknol.com" and see the SERP (and the HTML code showing the breadcrumbs)....Also, I observe the same problems with names which are only 1 or 2 words (not long enough), so problem is not related to length of text.

Comment: You have pages like this that are showing your entire breadcrumb (which only has three levels): https://fknol.com/stock/awf.php.  I still think it may have to do with the length of the breadcrumbs.  I can't find a four level breadcrumb that uses few words like that one.

Comment: It looks like you may need to work on your breadcrumbs in general anyway.   Take for example" https://fknol.com › Tallgrass Energy (TGE) Dividend History"   I would expect that to be "KNOL › TGE › Dividends".   Why wouldn't you have the general page about the company in the breadcrumbs?   Why do you use the full name and the abbreviations in parenthesis in the breadcrumbs?  Breadcrumbs don't need to spell things out that are the same as in the title.  Just the acronym there would be fine.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller for all your vital inputs. Really appreciate them. For AWF example that you cited, the SERP is "on its own" showing "https://fknol.com › stock › awf", while I have set something else (lengthier) in my HTML code...so apparently Google is taking the decision on its own if it is longer. For a 4-level breadcrumb that uses fewer words, please see https://fknol.com/etf/list/brazil.php which is showing only 3 (https://fknol.com › ETFs List › Brazil) while I have set them as (FKnol.com>ETFs List>Brazil>Brazil ETFs). So, short names used, but the last one is missing on SERP